# What happen when I uploaded a file to HDFS systems?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm a newbie to Hadoop/HDFS. I've read a few articles on how HDFS store the data but not fully understand it. Can someone explain it like I am 5?

Example:
Consider a cluster of 6 machines running HDFS (1 namenode, 5 datanodes). Each node in the cluster has a total of 1TB hard drive space and 2GB or main memory available. The cluster uses a block-size of 64 MB and a replication factor of 3. The master node maintains 100 bytes of metadata for each 64 MB block. Imagine that we upload a 128 GB file.

How much data does each datanode store?

Describe how HDFS will store the file?

Answer (score 1):

You start with HDFS client, which gets file information and calls namenode:

> Hey, I have a 128 GB file, where should i put it? (Create() method)

Namenode checks datanodes, and replies:

> Here is IP address or hostname of datanodes which are alive and have
> enough space.

Client starts chunking the data and streaming to datanodes.

chunks get stored on blocks in datanodes, hadoop might store your blocks on multiple datanodes.

now 128 GB is written on one or more datanodes as 2000 blocks (128GB / 64MB).
replication is 3, so hadoop finds new under replicated blocks, and starts replicating them to other datanodes according to replication policies and rack awareness.
at the end of replication, there will be 400 blocks of your replicated file on each datanode (2000 / 5) which means 25.6 gigabytes on each datanode. (64MB * 400).